# iPhone - At user event create objects in the view

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone programming, so I think part of the problem is that I don't know what I really want to google to find my answer.  I am looking for a method that allows a user to draw a line on the screen.  There is no guarantee that it will be straight, it can be curved or whatever.  I was thinking that I could create some small square image, and then as they draw, place them into a NSset.  But I am not really sure how to communicate each new object up to the view.  Up to this point, I've just been messing around with objects I put on the view and then assign movement to those, this is my first jump into on-the-fly object creation.

It might be that I just need to jump into a class/object type or even a tutorial, any guidance would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to create a 'paint' type application? There's an apple example for that:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html

This question is relevant, but might be too complex when you're just starting out:

[Improving Finger Painting Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355527/improving-finger-painting-performance)

If you're a bit more specific about what problem your app is to solve you might get some more specific answers.